# Writing to file cutting off second line - C

Tags: c, file-io

**Problem Statement**

When I am writing to a file, the second line gets cut off and the other lines do not.

---

**Code**

```
void write_out(char** quotes) {
    FILE* outFile = fopen(OUT_FILE, "w");

    if (outFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error with reading the file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Overwrites the contents of the file
    fprintf(outFile, "%s", quotes[0]);
    // Makes the file "appendable"
    outFile = fopen(OUT_FILE, "a");

    if (outFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error with reading the file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Write the rest of the quotes into the file
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_QUOTES; i++) {
        fprintf(outFile, "%s", quotes[i]);
    }

    fclose(outFile);
}
```

---

**Original Data**

```
Treat programmers like bad kids.

Good design adds value faster than it adds cost.

Perl is the only language that looks the same before and after RSA encryption.

Don't worry if it doesn't work right. If everything did, you would be out of a job.

A programming language is low level when its programs require attention to the irrelevant.
```

---

**Output (in the file)**

```
Treat programmers like bad kids.
 it adds cost. // Line cut off
Perl is the only language that looks the same before and after RSA encryption.
Don't worry if it doesn't work right. If everything did, you would be out of a job.
A programming language is low level when its programs require attention to the irrelevant.
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `outFile = fopen(OUT_FILE, "a");` --> Check its return value.  Perhaps you want to `freopen()` here?

Comment: You did not close the file before reopening it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes! Of course! That worked! Thank you and please post your answer so I can check it. Sometimes the simple things can be hard and get you.

Comment: `for (int i = 1;` Looks a bit strange - arrays start at 0.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, that's because I am overwriting the file with the first element of the quotes array before appending. So then, I would add the rest of the elements of the array to the file after that. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes no sense at all. There is no need to close and open in append mode. Just keep writing. But I would add a `newline` to the output: `fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", quotes[i]);`

Comment: @WeatherVane But doesn't "w" mode keep on overwriting the file whenever you write? Well, that was my assumption anyway, so that's why I went to append mode so I can ACTUALLY add more lines to the file.

Comment: No, the writing is sequential. But if you open an *existing* file in `"w"` mode the file will be over-written.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, then, please excuse my naivety. I didn't know that. I thought it just overwrote the file. I will fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not close the file before reopening it.

```
fprintf(outFile, "%s", quotes[0]);
fclose(outFile);                        // add this line
outFile = fopen(OUT_FILE, "a");
```

Comment: Thank you. The simple things can be hard to notice. I couldn't see it for 2 days. I just needed a fresh perspective from another person... And thank you for your quick answer!